# Why am I getting too few invocations back from this Spock test?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, spock, dagger-2

I'm new to the Spock testing framework, and I'm trying to do some testing for an android project I'm working on. These objects I'm currently testing are PJO, so they can be tested with regular Spock. For some reason I keep getting 0 invocations on the isAlive method called on one of my objects, but I know for a fact that it's invoked, sense I've literally run it in a debugger and it gets called. So I'm hoping someone can lead me to knowing what I'm doing wrong.

here's the code I'm testing:

```
 public void start(int startIndex, boolean overrideDownloadOnCellNetwork){
        this.downloadIndex = startIndex;
        this.overrideDownloadOnCellNetwork = overrideDownloadOnCellNetwork;
        if(checkConnectionType(overrideDownloadOnCellNetwork)){
            this.startTrackDownload();
        }
    }

    // I should simplify this at some point.
    private boolean checkConnectionType(boolean overrideDownloadOnCellNetwork) {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) masterService.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo connection = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(connection == null){
           broadcaster.broadcastError(DownloadEvent.DownloadEventType.ERROR_NO_NETWORK, downloadIndex);
            this.masterService.stop();
            return false;
        } else if(connection.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE && (userModel.isCellDownloadsAllowed() || overrideDownloadOnCellNetwork)){
            return true;
        } else if (connection.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            return true;
        } else {
            broadcaster.broadcastError(DownloadEvent.DownloadEventType.ERROR_NO_WIFI_CELL_DOWNLOAD_NOT_ALLOWED, downloadIndex);
            this.masterService.stop();
            return false;
        }
    }


    private void startTrackDownload(){
        if(trackList.size() > 0) {
            if (!downloadThread.isAlive()) {
                downloadThread.start();
            }
            downloadThread.downloadTrack(downloadIndex, trackList.size(), bookModel.getBookID(), userModel.getSessionID());
        }
    }
```

and here's my test code:

```
DownloaderImp downloader // this is a POJO

MasterService masterService
ActiveBookFactory activeBook
TrackListSubscriber trackListSubscriber
UserModel userModel
TrackSaver trackSaver
Notification notification
BookSaver bookSaver
BookModel bookModel

DownloadEventBroadcaster eventBroadcaster
DownloadThread downloadThread

Context context;


def "setup"(){

    masterService = Mock(MasterService)
    trackListSubscriber = Mock(TrackListSubscriber)
    userModel = Mock(UserModel )
    trackSaver = Mock(TrackSaver )
    notification = Mock(Notification )
    bookSaver = Mock(BookSaver)
    bookModel = Mock(BookModel)
    activeBook = Mock(ActiveBookFactory )
    downloadThread = Mock(DownloadThread)
    eventBroadcaster = Mock(DownloadEventBroadcaster)

    bookModel.getTrackModels() >> [new TrackModel(1), new TrackModel(2)]
    activeBook.get("downloading") >> bookModel
    bookModel.getId() >> 1

    downloader = new DownloaderImp(activeBook,
            trackListSubscriber,
            userModel,
            trackSaver,
            bookSaver,
            downloadThread,
            eventBroadcaster)

    context = Mock(Context)
    masterService.getContext() >> context
    downloader.setService(masterService)

}

def "should check if download thread is alive"(){
    given:
    def mockConnectionManager = Mock(ConnectivityManager)
    def mockNetworkInfo = Mock(NetworkInfo)
    masterService.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) >> mockConnectionManager
    mockConnectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() >> mockNetworkInfo
    mockNetworkInfo.getType() >> ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE

    when:
    downloader.start(0, true)

    then:
    1 * downloadThread.isAlive()
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried this in every configuration I can think of... and it always has this same issue.

Comment: AS you step through it does it terminate and then try and evaluate if the thread is alive? are you satisfying this condition connection.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE && (userModel.isCellDownloadsAllowed() || overrideDownloadOnCellNetwork)

Comment: @penguin it calls isAlive() which returns false, because it's a mock, and that's the default value that the mock returns for Boolean return types, so it then continues into the if block and executes `downloadThread.start()`

Comment: if isAlive always evaluates to false then your when then will always evaluate to 0 as well.

Comment: why is that? The `when` block is calling the start method, that will call the `startTrackDownload` method, which calls `isAlive`

Comment: how are downloadThread and downloader created ?

Comment: @JérémieB downloadThread is being created in the setup method. It's an instance variable of that test class, and it's a Mock() of the real object. The downloader object is the class being tested, so I'm creating a real object, also in the setup method. I'll add that code to my question just for clarification.

Comment: i assume you didn't see any warning about cglib missing in your class path ? if downloadThread is a class, you can mock it only through some bytecode generation. if you can debug your code, a "step-through" in isAlive() shouldn't call your class directly

Comment: @JérémieB I did not see anything about cglib missing. I think I have it... here's my gradel dependencies:
testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.3:grooid'

    testCompile 'org.robospock:robospock:1.0.0'

    testCompile 'org.robolectric:android-all:5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1'

    testCompile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:3.2.0'

    testCompile 'org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1'

Comment: @JérémieB could it have to do with isAlive method being defined on the Thread base class and not on my DownloadThread class? I think I read somewhere that can do something to your invocation tests.

Comment: mocking classes is always tricky, you should avoid it.. maybe try to use the Spying feature of spock, with downloadThread = Spy(DownloadThread) but i can't help more without a debugger ;-)

Comment: @JérémieB I agree mocking can be tricky. I appreciate your help. I will try that out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It been a while since this question was posted, but I will try to answer it anyway.

It is problematic to do unit test on Thread object, since `isAlive()` method is final boolean (you won't be able to mock it). In your code you should avoid using this method in internal logic. Maybe it is a good idea to use wrappers in this case (like interfaces), but most important thing is to count invocations of `start()` and `interrupt()` methods while testing threads.